# What protective materials exist that would extend the life of electrical appliances?

Tags: electrical, hvac, materials

I want to spend a lot of time in nature. Because of this, the electronics in my camper break down faster than they should.
I don't know the exact reason, they just stop working, but I guess due to harmful environment: high and low temperatures, humidity, water, mold, sand and marsh, insects, constant movement etc.

It's just about only those devices that are inside my home on wheels, and not outside, so rain or wind should not be taken into account.

The only thing I'm protected from now is falling. All devices are attached securely using wooden holders and sometimes magnets.
Can you advise what protective materials exist that would extend the life of electrical appliances?

Comment: Did you buy the cheapest "home" rated appliances? When you want things to survive in tough conditions then you need to buy quality.

Comment: Vibration, in addition to the insults you've mentioned; you might want to consider padded storage or shock mounting, as anyone who travels with electronics on business does.  Magnets are not likely to be an issue for most devices.  (Note: "electronics" usually does not include appliances unless they have something more complicated than a motor and switch. Which specific appliances are an issue?)

Comment: From all the VanLife videos I see on Youtube, most lifestyle campers have a culture of  **cheap-@ss cr*p straight off Amazon Marketplace" (functionally, eBay) which is China's worst and not certified by any safety agencies at all.  A few bright lights use Dickenson heaters (insead of no-name Chinese diesel heaters), or Midnight Solar charge controllers at 8 times the price of Aliexpress.  *And y'know what? Their campers work.*

Answer (score 1):

A dehumidifier!

If you take apart one of the items that failed I could almost guarantee you the metal components and connections are rusted.

Comment: That's a good point. And one option might be rechargeable desiccants.  Desiccants are those funny little pouches that come in many products (vitamins, seaweed paper etc.) They make rechargeable ones that you bake in the oven to dry out again. Dry them out a bunch at a time, throw them in Ziploc bags til needed, then when stowing the electronics, put them bags with a desiccant.

Answer (score -1):

As it seems you are exposing appliances to harsh conditions including humidity and vibration, consider getting appliances designed for use in boats. They should be designed and built to resist corrosion, vibration and humidity.

For example, marine versions of receivers and speaker systems are easily available.

Comment: Cell phones work in outside environment, it is not harsh conditions inside a camper.

Comment: @Ruskes I'm considering extremes of heat and cold, humidity, and vibration as "harsh conditions" not normally experienced by household appliances.

Comment: Downvoter - could you explain the reasoning for the downvote? Thx